# Why is this Javascript code not writing to the webpage?

Tags: javascript, forms, document.write

I have just started learning Javascript. I want "Hello World!" to be written to a webpage once a user clicks a button. I have tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{
document.write("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get it to do a `window.alert("Hello World!")` but not do `document.write("Hello World!")` for some reason. What happens is the button disappears and no text is displayed. My guess is that the problem is in the `document.write` but I do not know how to work around it. Any suggestions?

Comment: #thryle, this is working for me, FF 3.6

Comment: Think about it; if you use Document.write you are effectively changing the page.  HTML is not dynamic, so everything would need to load once again.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver Live View and also Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the document has already been written at that point. You can set text like so:

```
<button id="lol">blah</button>
<script>
    function setText( obj, to ) {
        obj.textContent? obj.textContent = to : obj.innerText = to;
    }
    var lol = document.getElementById('lol')

    lol.onclick = function() {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        setText( p, 'hi' );
    }
</script>
```

Another popular but often looked down technique would be `innerHTML`.

Comment: How do I make a new document then?

Comment: you don't. you use alternate methods like creating new text nodes and elements or altering existing ones.

Comment: Why is innerHTML looked down upon? It's much simpler.

Comment: It's frowned upon because it wasn't initially a standard, though nowadays I would assume people are more lenient because the jQuery `html` method is just innerHTML and innerHTML has become part of the HTML 5 spec.

Answer (score 2):

Document.write is used to write to the currently loading HTML file. Once the page has been loaded, and a user begins interacting with the page, document.write is useless.